# Discerning or evaluating prophesies

Tags: 1-corinthians, 1-john, 1-thessalonians

1 Corinthians 14:29 NKJV)

> 29 Let two  or three prophets speak, and let the others judge.

1 Thessalonians 5:19-22 (NKJV)

> 19 Do not quench the Spirit.  20 Do not despise  prophecies. 21 Test all things; hold fast what is good. 22  Abstain from every form of evil.  Blessing and Admonition

1 John 4:1-2 (NKJV)

> 1 Beloved, do not believe every spirit, but test the spirits,  whether they are of God; because many false prophets  have gone out into the world. 2 By this you know the Spirit  of God: Every spirit that confesses that Jesus Christ has  come in the flesh is of God

It seems testing and evaluating of prophesies was common and even commanded. If someone had the gift of prophecy and was prophesying why would others test and evaluate his prophesies?

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question by quoting 1 John 4:1-2?

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer to your question, I believe, is that it is wrong to presume that anyone prophesying is doing so through the power of God.  This is the reason behind the admonition in the other verse you quoted (1 John 4:1-2).  It is also the reason behind Paul's admonition in his other letter to the Corinthians (11:13-14):

> *For such are false apostles, deceitful workers, transforming themselves into the apostles of Christ. And no marvel; for Satan
>   himself is transformed into an angel of light.*